# DI from a main Method in console application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a class

```
public class A
{
    public A(IB b)
    {
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IB,B>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        //How to call Method1 of classA
        classA a = new classA(); 
     }
}
```

How do I call `Method1()` from `Main` method?

I get a compile time error as "No overload methods exist".

Comment: You have to add all classes to your service provider (seems you missed to add `classA`). Then to get an instance you have to call `var a = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClassA>();` If this class contains a dependency to `B` it will be created and injected.

Comment: We do not know if the type `classA` has a method called `Method1` because you did not show us the definition of the type `classA`. You show us the definition of the class `A` but that is not the same as `classA`

Comment: Note that the .NET and ASP.NET tags refer to .NET Framework, not .NET Core, so adding them makes your question less clear. Also, your question relates to .NET Core in general, not specifically ASP.NET Core (web framework), so I've changed your tag for you.

Answer (score 5):

The DI in an application neeeds to be bootstrapped somewhere. In for example ASP.NET this happens inside the framework, 'out of sight'.

Here you will have to register & resolve the A class:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<IB,B>()
        .AddTransient<A>()     // Transient or Singleton, it depends
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    //How to call Method1 of classA
    // classA a = new classA(); 

    var a  = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<A>();
 }
```

Comment: Not really, you can use ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance to resolve the constructor parameters.

Comment: Yes, that works too. I just always used this pattern in the rare cases where I needed it. I do think that CreateInstance belongs to a lower level, for internal use by the DI. But it is public, I'm sure there are use cases for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register `A` as well, then use the service provider to get the instance. The service provider will inject `IB` into your instance of `A`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<IB,B>()
        .AddSingleton<A>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var a = serviceProvider.GetService<A>();
    a.Method1();
 }
```

Comment: It does not make sense to register A if you do not want to use it via dependency injection. You can just create the instance as show in my answer below.

Comment: Sure.... you could also just write `new A(new B())` and skip the service provider entirely. Somehow I think that defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

To have the dependecy injection features in a console application make sure you include Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in you project.

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
public class A
{
    public A(IB b)
    {
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
    }
}

public interface IB
{
}

public class B : IB
{
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
           .AddSingleton<IB, B>()
           .BuildServiceProvider();

        //How to call Method1 of classA
        var a = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<A>(serviceProvider);

        a.Method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add DI as a package to a Console app.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Could you add some words about the adventage of using `ActivatorUtilities` instead of simply using `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<A>()`?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the instance. If you use CreateInstance you have full control about the lifecycle, you can create and destroy it whenever you need to, and garbage collection will do the clean-up when it is no longer required. Furthermore, you don't have to care about the scope that controls whether a new instance will be created, or an existing instance is re-used. If class A implements a service that is required in various locations of you code and should be kept alive and re-used you should register it as a service; otherwise I would just create the instance.